# why replaced div content gone after refresh?

Tags: jquery, html, django

It's my first time i'm practising jquery with django. I just want to replace the div content with new content when success user authentication. So far my code is working but whenever user refreshes the page it returned to default html. How do i prevent this ..?

html

```
<span class="logo">
   <div id="pre-user">Welcome <strong>Guest</strong></div>            
</span>
```

js

```
success: function(data) {
    if (data.result != "success") {
        // error message
        alert("Sorry, something went wrong... try again.");
    } else {
        $("#pre-user").html("Welcome <strong>" + data.userEmail + "</strong>");
```

Comment: Does your code check if a current authenticated user is already logged in? Your js snippet seems to only show when a user tries to log in.

Comment: in django i can do with request.user.is_authenticated but i'm talking about without page refresh but if suppose user refresh the page then what should i do ..? i need best practise for this ..

Comment: when they push reload; i would then have the backend fill in the correct information. Only use JS when initially logging in as you have.

Answer (score 1):

Any markup that you add via JavaScript will only be present for one request cycle. If you perform another GET request, even if to the same url, the dynamically added markup will not be present in the DOM.

To do that, you have a couple of options:

1. Persist the data from the ajax post in the database, session, etc.
2. Persist the data using localStorage on the client-side.

If you persist it server-side, you can render it out using Django template tags. If you persist it in localStorage, you would need to render it via JavaScript. Which one you choose completely depends on the needs of your application.

Answer (score 0):

i would do this way:

```
<span class="logo">
  <div id="pre-user">
      {% if user.is_authenticated %}
          Welcome <strong>{{ user.email }}</strong>
      {% else %}
          Welcome <strong>Guest</strong>
      {% endif %}  
  </div>            
</span>
```

this way, you can keep your js which just changes the `#pre-user`'s html content for now, if user reloads the page, the changed content will stay there since it is now backend-connected.